# How do I automatically create a subscription to a topic, if it doesn't already exist?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have an already existing topic on the azure portal, but I do not have any subscriptions. 
And I have written a function in my project that listens to this topic.

I want to make it work so that in case I didn't manually create a subscription to a topic with the same name that I specified in my code, my code will automatically create it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When receiving messages with Azure Service Bus trigger, you can either use a queue or a topic with a subscription. A topic alone will not work as messages cannot be retrieved from a topic directly, only can be sent to a topic. Therefore you'd need to define both `TopicName` and `SubscriptionName` for your `ServiceBusTopicTrigger`.

Both the topic and the subscription have to be created ahead of the time. Functions SDK will not create it for you. And the function cannot be triggered if the proper topic/subscription combination is not in place to listen to. You can do that in a few ways. One of those is [Azure CLI commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/topic/subscription).

Answer (score 0):

Messages can be sent to a Service Bus Topic and messages can be received only from the subscriptions within the Topic. Azure Functions with Service Bus Trigger can be created only for Service Bus Queues and topic subscriptions.

> It is not possible to receive the messages directly from the Service Bus Topic.

Following work around may help you

1. Create a Function App with Event grid trigger or Http trigger.
2. The Function App should get the Service Topic using
   Microsoft.ServiceBus SDK.
3. If the subscription count of the topic is zero, create a topic subscription.
4. The created function must be triggered before the message is sent to the topic.